# converting a sql query without sub query

Tags: sql, rdbms

Is there a way to convert this query into one without having the subquery in where clause?

```
      select distinct 
          ie.install_id
        , ie.sp_id
        , ie.device_config_id
        from d1_sp sp
        inner join install_evt ie  
            on ie.sp_id = sp.sp_id
        where ie.install_dttm = (select max(iemax.install_dttm)
                                    from install_evt iemax
                                    where iemax.sp_id = sp.sp_id)
```

Comment: You could use a nested query or a cte with a window aggregate. What is the problem you are trying to solve and what is the database?

Comment: . [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @Stu I’m trying to convert this using spark api query. I wasn’t warble you find a straightforward match for a sub query in where clause. So I was trying to see if this query could be modified or broken down into multiple queries so that I can update my spark data frame query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      select distinct 
          ie.install_id
        , ie.sp_id
        , ie.device_config_id
        , max(ie.install_dttm)
        from d1_sp sp
        inner join install_evt ie  
            on ie.sp_id = sp.sp_id
group by           ie.install_id, ie.sp_id, ie.device_config_id
```

if you need additional grouping you can use an order by